# Tutorial for using Recommendify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recommendation-engine

I'm a beginner at Ruby on Rails and like to ask for examples on using the Recommendify gem, specifically, how do I add the required input matrix and retrieved the output. Also, I'd like to clarify if the setup stated in the [readme](https://github.com/paulasmuth/recommendify) requires me to create a model, if so how do i invoke the recommendify library?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question is considered off-topic because it is asking to help find an off-site tutorial. If you have a specific question, please feel free to ask that. On a side note, this gem was last updated over three years ago. There may be something else out there that is updated more frequently.

Comment: hmm okay, just wanted to ask for advice on creating the input matrix for that gem